# Recover data from RAID1 with one disk in rebuilding state

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, mdadm, raid1

I am attempting to recover data on a MDADM RAID1 array with one HDD that suffered a mechanical failure and another that is stuck in a rebuilding state.

I have two 2TB HDDs that were installed on a machine running under a mdadm RAID1 array named /dev/md1.

Sda1 and Sdb1 were both part of the array. Sda had a mechanical failure and it's been replaced with a new HDD with the same capacity, on which a new partition of the same size was created.

Upon attempting to add sda1 to the array I've received the following error:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md1 --manage --add /dev/sda1
mdadm: cannot load array metadata from /dev/md1
```

### What I've tried

I've been following this guide (https://ahelpme.com/linux/recovering-md-array-and-mdadm-cannot-get-array-info-for-dev-md0/) to attempt to 'activate' the array.

These are the steps of the guide:

1. Remove ALL current configuration by issuing multiple stop commands with mdadm, no inactive raids or any raids should be reported in “/proc/mdstat”.
2. Rename mdadm configuration files in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
3. Rescan for MD devices with mdadm. The mdadm will load the configuration from your disks.
4. Add the missing partitions to your software raid devices.

I've executed the first two steps.

On running step 3, the raid was discovered but, unlike the guide, it seems sdb1 is in rebuilding state and the array cannot be started because of it.

I'm reluctant to try anything involving --force since I'm unsure as to the exact state of the data and the fact that, unfortunately, the entirety of the data is very precious.

### My questions

- How can I recover the data?
- How can I know what files on the disk that is 'Rebuilding' are 'incomplete' or corrupted?
- Why, when running `sudo mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md1` it says raid0 but when running `sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb1` it says raid1?

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

### System info

```
:/$ sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose

mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop10
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop9
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/loop8
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdc2
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sda
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/sdb (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 00000000)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop7 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 118a6b61)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop7
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop6 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got e7e108a6)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop6
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop5 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 3a23b8f9)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop5
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop4 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got 3a23b8f9)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop4
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop3 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got e7e108a6)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop3
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop2 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got a6eff301)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop2
mdadm: No super block found on /dev/loop1 (Expected magic a92b4efc, got e06997af)
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/1, slot 1.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md/1
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md/1 as 1 <---------
mdadm: /dev/md/1 assembled from 0 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array. <---------  
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
:/$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1   43.1M squashfs          loop /snap/certbot/1670
loop2   76.2M squashfs          loop /snap/lxd/22340
loop3   55.5M squashfs          loop /snap/core18/2253
loop4   61.9M squashfs          loop /snap/core20/1270
loop5   61.9M squashfs          loop /snap/core20/1328
loop6   55.5M squashfs          loop /snap/core18/2284
loop7   43.3M squashfs          loop /snap/snapd/14295
loop8   43.4M squashfs          loop /snap/snapd/14549
loop9   76.3M squashfs          loop /snap/lxd/22358
loop10  43.1M squashfs          loop /snap/certbot/1788
sda      1.8T                   disk
`-sda1   1.8T ext4              part
sdb      1.8T                   disk
`-sdb1   1.8T linux_raid_member part
sdc    465.8G                   disk
|-sdc1 517.7M vfat              part /boot/efi
`-sdc2   400G ext4              part /
```

```
:/$ sudo mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md1

/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0 <---------
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 1

              Name : xxxx:1  (local to host xxxx)
              UUID : e6193d43:0b7be2b3:fd27645d:4cb0f619
            Events : 14150

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
```

```
:/$ sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb1

/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x83
     Array UUID : e6193d43:0b7be2b3:fd27645d:4cb0f619
           Name : xxxx:1  (local to host xxxx)
  Creation Time : Tue May 11 14:46:10 2021
     Raid Level : raid1 <---------
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3905983761 (1862.52 GiB 1999.86 GB)
     Array Size : 1952991880 (1862.52 GiB 1999.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 12630656 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 58da91c5:df6f5be4:91860671:53d40e22

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug 16 23:01:12 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : b1e8f237 - correct
         Events : 14150

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : inactive sdb1[3]
      1952991880 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```